# Is anyone mining the Dragonglass?

Tags: game-of-thrones

This post contains spoilers of season 7.

As we know, Jon Snow went to Dragonstone to convince Danaerys to let him mine the Dragonglass.

After the events of episode 6 and 7, we know that Jon Snow is not there anymore, with the men he came with (At least that what I think).

So I need a confirmation, no one is mining the Dragonglass now, right?

Or did Jon Snow leave some men to do that task?

Comment: As far as I know we don't know. However, it wouldn't much sense to have no one mining the most valuable resource in Westeros so we can assume the answer is yes.

Comment: What makes you think he took al the men he came with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>We see that, before he heads off, there's Northmen mining away quite happily, though when Jon returns to the North we only see 1 ship (as far as I recall), and we only see the Magnificent 7(ish) in action afterwards so it's entirely likely that he left a contingent of Northmen to keep mining.</strike>

It sounds like something Jon would do, after all, Winter is Coming.

As pointed out below, Daenerys supplies the men (presumably non-combatants) and supplies to mine the Dragonglass, so there is no reason for it to stop. Although Dany's armies are occupied, the men we see transporting dragonglass from the mines don't particularly look like soldiers.

Comment: I've just rewatched the scene when they leave and I can confirm that we don't see anyone still mining as they push the boats out.

Comment: Dany did offer to have _her_ people mine it for him. Boats may be irrelevant if Dany's people are mining it and storing it, planning for a later shipment (e.g. because the first shipment was on its way)

Comment: @Flater Did she? I watched the scene without sound on so couldn't tell. Have you got a quote for it as it backs up my theory in my answer anyway?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder: I can't listen to confirm it (I'm at work), but [this scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PU-L5Cn2-Ucp) should be the one. [A script I found](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=game-of-thrones&episode=s07e03) also contains it: _"I will allow you to mine the dragonglass and forge weapons from it.
Any resources or men you need, I will provide for you."_ Given that Jon and Davos traveled alone, the northmen could have come over, or Jon could have accepted Dany's offer. It's not explicitly confirmed either way, I think.

Comment: @Flater Yep you're right, I remembered it wrong, I'll amend my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**TL:DR:** We don't know if anyone is still mining, however, we can speculate.

I've just re-watched the entire Jon leaving Dragonstone scene and I can confirm we see no one mining away.

However, Jon is a smart guy and Dargonglass is now the most valuable resource in Westeros. It would make sense for there to still be people mining away. But it wouldn't make sense for him to leave his own men. He already doesn't have enough to hold the wall and should Dany change her mind she can then take his men captive. Therefore, I doubt that he would have left some of his own men.

Dany has a massive army and most of the Dothraki appear to still be at Dragonstone. It makes more sense for Jon's men to have shown the Dothraki what to do and have them mine it out.

The [following scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PU-L5Cn2-Uc) and [this script](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=game-of-thrones&episode=s07e03) seem to back up this idea:

> "I will allow you to mine the dragonglass and forge weapons from it. Any resources or men you need, I will provide for you."

Though it isn't conclusive either way.

On the other hand, Jon knows it is a valuable resource and needs it across the North as quickly as possible. he could have left some skilled men down in the mines to have the process go faster.